# how to do fragmentation attack via ubuntu machine

Tags: snort, fragmentation

I wish to test my system which has snort installed on it.
I want to do fragmentation attack such as tiny fragment attack and wish that it should be logged by snort.

any suggestions? any graphical software available ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is list of Packet Crafting Tools. I have used Hping to test firewalls.

http://compsec.org/security/index.php/packet-crafting-tools.html

Comment: thanks :) . .  can u give me a simple example as how to do a fragmentation attack ??

Comment: This link should help you http://www.indepthdefense.com/2009/08/originally-posted-on-httppauldotcom.html